# How to draw in a panel calling the method from another class

Tags: c#, methods

I'm trying to call a method which draws something in a panel from another class, but something doesn't work.

This is the drawing method:

```
class Dibujo
   {
       public void Dibujar(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
       {
           Form2 ventana2 = new Form2();
           Graphics g = ventana2.panel1.CreateGraphics();
           Pen Boli = new Pen(Brushes.Green);


           Point Inicio = new Point(200, 100);
           Point Final = new Point(400, 300);
           g.DrawLine(Boli, Inicio, Final);


       }
   }
}
```

And here is were I call it:

```
 private void btnDibujar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

           Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
           Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
           PaintEventArgs pe = new PaintEventArgs(g,rect);
           Pen Boli = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
           g.DrawLine(Boli,100,100,100,300);

           Dibujo panel = new Dibujo();

           panel.Dibujar(sender,pe);

       }
```

So the idea is that when I click the button btnDibujar_click a simple line is drawn in the panel but it doesn't work. I know that the code probably has a lot of mistakes but I'm a beginner and I'm learning by myself so all kinds of advice is welcome.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO - can you post your complete code - what is Dibujo ?

Comment: You should draw in the panel Paint event

Comment: Sorry! Dibujo is the class that has the Dibujar method

Comment: Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..
You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..
The correct way is to keep a list of things to draw and whenever that list changes `Invalidate` the control you draw on. - You will need references to the Panel. Make it `internal` !